# Passing parameters to a custom page template using clean urls

Tags: url-rewriting, templates, page-template, htaccess

I am now passing parameters to a custom template in the following format

```
www.example.com/?pageid=12&rid=24&title=this-is-the-title
```

I have created two tables . So I need to fetch data and display them on those pages.

I would like it to  be using clean URL format like:

```
www.example.com/pageid/12/rid/24/title/this-is-the-title
```

Can anyone tell how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Totally possible, but you have to be mindful of your variable slugs to avoid conflicts. Take a look at this article on the WordPress codex... this is probably the hook you would want to use and it shows a sample rewrite array... http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array

Answer (score 4):

[`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) allows you to turn the pretty url into variables.

- numbers:   `(\d*)`
- section:   `/rid/` or `/pageid/`
- slug:      `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+`

Here is a class to register the rewrite and handle the request if a match has been found.

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'CPTURLRewrite' ) ):

    class CPTURLRewrite {
        const ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME  = 'pageid';
        const ENDPOINT_QUERY_PARAM = '__pageid';

        // WordPress hooks

        public function init() {
            add_filter( 'query_vars', array ( $this, 'add_query_vars' ), 0 );
            add_action( 'parse_request', array ( $this, 'sniff_requests' ), 0 );
            add_action( 'init', array ( $this, 'add_endpoint' ), 0 );
        }

        // Add public query vars

        public function add_query_vars( $vars ) {

            // add all the things we know we'll use

            $vars[] = static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_PARAM;
            $vars[] = 'pageid';
            $vars[] = 'rid';
            $vars[] = 'title';

            return $vars;
        }

        // Add API Endpoint

        public function add_endpoint() {

            // numbers:   (\d*)
            // section:   /rid/
            // slug:      ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+

            add_rewrite_rule( '^' . static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_NAME . '/(\d*)/rid/(\d*)/title/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?', 'index.php?' . static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_PARAM . '=1&pageid=$matches[1]&rid=$matches[2]&title=$matches[3]', 'top' );

            //////////////////////////////////
            flush_rewrite_rules( false ); //// <---------- REMOVE THIS WHEN DONE
            //////////////////////////////////
        }

        // Sniff Requests

        public function sniff_requests( $wp_query ) {
            global $wp;

            if ( isset(
                $wp->query_vars[ static::ENDPOINT_QUERY_PARAM ],
                $wp->query_vars[ 'pageid' ],
                $wp->query_vars[ 'rid' ],
                $wp->query_vars[ 'title' ] ) ) {
                $this->handle_request(); // handle it
            }
        }

        // Handle Requests

        protected function handle_request() {
            global $wp;

            // (optional) act on the query vars

            $pageid = $wp->query_vars[ 'pageid' ];
            $rid = $wp->query_vars[ 'rid' ];
            $title = $wp->query_vars[ 'title' ];

            // (optional) select your custom template

            add_filter( 'template_include', function( $original_template ) {
                return __DIR__ . '/custom.php';
            } );
        }
    }

    $wpCPTURLRewrite = new CPTURLRewrite();
    $wpCPTURLRewrite->init();

endif; // CPTURLRewrite
```

---

### UPDATE

I found a simpler way to handle this.

http://example.com/pageid/333/rid/444/title/your-title-here/

This new way utilizes [`add_rewrite_tag`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) with `_` to run the query for a page's ID without messing up the main query. In the example above, `333` would just modify the query to look for that post ID in [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). You could just as easily modify [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) or [`template_include`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include).

```
/**
 * Register a rewrite endpoint for the API.
 */
function prefix__init() {

    // add tags with `_` prefix to avoid screwing up query
    add_rewrite_tag( '%_pageid%', '(\d*)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%_rid%', '(\d*)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%_title%', '([a-zA-Z\d\-_+]+)' );

    // create URL rewrite
    add_rewrite_rule( '^pageid/(\d*)/rid/(\d*)/title/([a-zA-Z\d\-_+]+)?', 'index.php?_pageid=$matches[1]&_rid=$matches[2]&_title=$matches[3]', 'top' );

    // required once after rules added/changed
    // flush_rewrite_rules( true );
}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix__init' );

/**
 * Handle data (maybe) passed to the API endpoint.
 *
 * @param $query
 */
function prefix__pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( isset( $query->query_vars[ '_pageid' ], $query->query_vars[ '_rid' ], $query->query_vars[ '_title' ] ) ) {

        // set the query to search for a page using `_pageid`
        $query->set( 'p', $query->query_vars[ '_pageid' ] );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'prefix__pre_get_posts' );
```

To reference all the params passed later:

```
/**
* Debug the query params at any point
*/
function prefix__show_query_args() {
 global $wp_query;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( array (
        'pageid' => $wp_query->query_vars[ '_pageid' ],
        'rid'    => $wp_query->query_vars[ '_rid' ],
        'title'  => $wp_query->query_vars[ '_title' ],
        'file'   => __FILE__,
        'line'   => __LINE__,
    ) );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

---

### REFERENCE

- https://10up.github.io/Engineering-Best-Practices/php/#performance

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution this might be it (haven't tested the code so might not be so simple if it's not working...) or atleast it give some hint what you need to do. If you visit http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/ you will find a bonus prize: A Rewrite Rule Generator in the article. I have used this before but not in a situation exactly like this. Try to combine that function with something like this:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%pageid%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%rid%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%title%','([^&]+)');

/* Generate rewrite rules. */
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'example_add_rewrite_rules' );
function example_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $new_rules = eg_generate_rewrite_rules( 'post' , array('pageid','rid','title')); //    post = the post type you use
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

/* Flush rewrite rules on theme activation only. */
add_action( 'load-themes.php', 'frosty_flush_rewrite_rules' );
function frosty_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( 'themes.php' == $pagenow && isset( $_GET['activated'] ) )
        flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

If you don't want to use the eg_generate_rewrite_rules function, you need to set up the rules yourself. You can find information on how to do that in that article.

More info:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag