# Passing URL parameters to WordPress pages and pretty url

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

I create shortcode like this

```
function test_func( $atts ) {   

    return $_GET['myvar'];
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'test_func' );
```

and one page with this name myparameters

so this is the final url

```
http://website.com/myparameters
```

if I try this works perfect

```
http://website.com/myparameters/?myvar=theparameter
```

But i like have pretty url or friendly url like this

```
http://website.com/myparameters/theparameter/
```

But show page not found.

I try some tutorial like this [LINK](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89164/passing-parameters-to-a-custom-page-template-using-clean-urls) but nothing happen

Comment: [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257977/4771) will work for you.

Comment: @Milo well, i investigate a litle more, if use global $wp; $view = $wp->query_vars['myvar']; to get the parameter and now work fine with add_rewrite_rule and return $view in shortcode function, I'll leave the complete example when ready.

Answer (score 0):

You're forming a GET request, i.e. ?var=1&var2=2 but you've sent it as a POST request, you need to send the request as a GET request so that the variables are displayed in the url bar as you expect them to be displayed.

Comment: the @milo Link example is the answers only we need use global $wp; to get the value like this $wp->query_vars['myvar'];

Comment: I misunderstood your question that you wanted to know why you were getting one format vs. another format in the url bar. Good that you found a solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full example, it works very well with one parameter, just change the id to that of your page.

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) { 
    global $wp;
    $view = $wp->query_vars['jp_stn'];
    return $view;
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );


function cdl_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'pronosticador/([-a-z]+)/?$',
        'index.php?page_id=52&jp_stn=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cdl_rewrite_rule' );

function cdl_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'jp_stn';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cdl_query_vars' );
```

Comment: @Milo  What you think about this? in the correct way to get value with pretty url

Comment: @kromosome What you think about this? in the correct way to get value with pretty url

Comment: Note: Flush Permalink

Answer (score 0):

To achieve pretty URLs with parameters in WP, you can utilize the rewrite rules provided by WordPress along with a custom endpoint or a rewrite rule.

you need to register a custom `rewrite` rule to handle the pretty URL. Add the following code to your themes `functions.php` file

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^myparameters/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=myparameters&myvar=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10);

function custom_query_vars($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'myvar';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_query_vars', 10, 1);
```

After adding the rewrite rule, you need to flush the rewrite rules for Wp to recognize the new rule. You can do this by visiting the `"Settings" > "Permalinks"` page in your WP admin area

Update your shortcode function to retrieve the value of `myvar` from the query variables instead of `$_GET`

```
function test_func($atts) {
    $myvar = get_query_var('myvar');
    return $myvar;
}
add_shortcode('test', 'test_func');
```