# WordPress How to rewrite URL for custom pages

Tags: htaccess

I have created Test folder in main directory having file test.php
`https://example.com/test/test.php?id=123&z=dnfjk` after rewriting i want to create `https://example.com/test/test/123/dnfjk`

I have used following code htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$  https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$  https://example.com//$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it shows 404 error

Comment: So you're not using the WordPress environment but a custom .php file?

Comment: So you want a kind of an automatic url generator for your test paramters? That is hard to create. Search for `human readable url wordpress` or just get inspired by this direct post answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/258214/141935

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is completely outside of WordPress then... to rewrite `/test/test/123/dnfjk` to `/test/test.php?id=123&z=dnfjk`, then you could do something like the following in the `/test/.htaccess` file (not the WordPress `.htaccess` file in the document root):

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(\d+)/([a-z]+)$ test.php?id=$1&z=$2 [L]
```

MultiViews needs to be disabled for this to work.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$  https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*).php$  https://example.com//$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

These are external redirects (as opposed to *internal rewrites*) and don't seem to relate to your example at all?

Note that you change the URL in your application, you don't issue a *redirect* to do this. You would only need the redirect if the old URL (with URL parameters) had already been indexed and/or linked to by third parties.